# How to return Mongodb js return value to shell script

Tags: mongodb-query

I m getting started with MongoDb scripting. My requirement is to query the mongodb for a process status and based on it kick start another process, in shell script. I ve written the following js to query and return the value from mongodb :

```
var statusValue=db.Collections.find({"Name":"UV"},{Status:1,_id:0}).sort({Sequence:-1}).limit(1).map( function(u) { return u.Status; } );

print (statusValue);
```

I call this js from a shell script. Is there a way to return the value of 'statusValue' to the calling shell?

Answer (score 1):

Use "--eval" option to get return value. For example:
    return=`mongo localhost/test --quiet --eval 'db.version()'`
Replace "db.version()" with your own expression.
Refer to [the offical document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#eval-option).